# Replacing duplicates in a randomized 2 dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I am having some trouble with my class project, essentially what I want to do is spawn objects randomly which so far is working perfectly, they are spawned from an 2d array that stores X and Z which have been randomly generated within reasonable distance. The issue I am having is objects being placed inside each other due to lack of duplicate detection. I need to go through the 2d array, see if any X and Y co-ords match and randomize any matches found. Sorry if this doesn't make a lot of sense, i'm not too good at explaining things but perhaps you could take a look at my current detection method and give me some tips?

```
for (int k = 0; k <= NumofShrooms - 1; k++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= NumofShrooms - 1;)
    {
        if (k == i)
        {
            i++;
        }

        if (SpawnArray[k][2] == SpawnArray[i][2])
        {
            SpawnArray[k][2] = rand() % 16 + 1;
            i = 0;
        }
        else i++;
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there an error or do you only want hints on how to improve the performance of the detection?

Comment: Can you rephrase (clarify) "objects being placed inside each other" and "I need to randomize any matches"?

Comment: So basically I need it to go through the array, find duplicates and replace them so every object placed has a unique position, for example if the array at position [0] [1] is the same as [4][1] then it will generate a new random number and check for duplicates, if none are found it will check [1] [1] with all other entries to find duplicates and so on. The problem is that the objects still spawn inside each other and any help would be appreciated because I'm stumped at this point

Comment: Just to clarify the objects spawn at [0][1][2] , 1 being Z and 2 being X so each array entry has a sub array with X and Z coordinates to use